# Prove that $(xy+xz+yz)^2 \leq (2x^2 + y^2)(2z^2 + y^2)$

Tags: inequality

What is the easiest way way to prove that $$(xy+xz+yz)^2 <= (2x^2 + y^2)(2z^2 + y^2)$$ holds for real $x$, $y$, $z$?

I've solved it using some "advanced" mathematics, but I would like to know some **elementary** solution (for example, using ***Cauchy inequality*** or something like that).

Comment: Use Cachy-Schwarz

Comment: Write $(2x^2+y^2)(2z^2+y^2)=(x^2+x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2+z^2)$ then appeal to C-S.

Comment: I didn't know this inequality, thank you ;)

Comment: What's the "advanced" mathematics you've used to solve it?

Comment: AFAIK Cauchy inequality is the same as C-S / Cauchy-Schwarz, C-B-S etc it is all the same inequality.